# Azure-Function eventhub trigger issue with Binding parameters to complex objects

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am trying to send the data to IoT Hub which sends the data to the stream analytics and then to Event Hub. Azure function gets triggered as soon as the message is entered into the event hub. The problem I am facing is that when I send 10 messages from the VS Code(send D2C message to IoT Hub) option. The function throws this error:

> Binding parameters to complex objects (such as 'Object') uses
>   Json.NET serialization.
>   1. Bind the parameter type as 'string' instead of 'Object' to get the raw values and avoid JSON deserialization, or
>   2. Change the queue payload to be valid json. The JSON parser failed: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: Path '', line 0,
>   position 0.

As per my investigation, this message points to the invalid json, however this is not the case. My json is correct and valid because my function parses it correctly. This problem occurs when I start scaling upwards(send more messages in less intervals) to the IoT Hub. I am not sure what is causing it. If the message is not correct then the function should throw the error for every message rather than randomly throwing the error. In addition, this exception is not caught because this happens at the azure side not within my function code. My `function.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "main.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "myhubName",
      "connection": "myConnectionString",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing in this file? I do not want to scale down my cardinality(one) option since the current option is the recommended one. similar issue can be seen [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1830). In this case they might not have a valid json but a string. Although in my case its always json so I cannot use `dataType: string` property.

main.py

```
import logging
import sys
from sys import path
import os
import traceback
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import json

def main(event: func.EventHubEvent):
  try:
    # prints the message
    print("*******************************************")
    print(event.iothub_metadata)
    print(event.get_body())

  except:
        # Logs the stack trace to the root level when errors occurs
    logging.error("Unexpected Error: " + traceback.format_exc())
    pass
```

Comment: Does the 10 messages exceeds 1M?

Comment: No, for 10 messages it would be around 80 KB Maximum.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/411), you need to create **`DefaultType`** for the EventHubs trigger attribute and making sure that it is registered in the metadata provider

example code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/blob/dev/endtoendtests/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/functions/endtoend/EventHubTriggerTests.java#L27).

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could provide the sample code for python. In addition, please mention what setting do I need to provide in function json. The thread you provided pointing to python code is 404, thus please give the code example here as your answer so I could mark it as the correct one because links can be down or updated but question remains here for next readers :).

Comment: check if this would help https://github.com/alexkarcher-msft/PythonOpenHackTheFinalDestination/blob/b921bd8e718270f378f12f379d8c8ac196c31d3d/Challenge1/.python_packages/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/functions_worker/bindings/eventhub.py

Comment: The code you provided only fetches the details from the `event` object. It does not set any data type or something. My understanding is that the default type is json and if you want the string type then you need to declare your datatype. It makes sense because my function works till 5 messages. If data type was incorrect then it would not have worked on any message. The problem is random. My understanding is when it is invoked at the azure side then the problem rises. I have even checked it with the default code provided by azure that means my code is not making any issue.

Comment: if possible post the code on how you are sending it

Comment: I have posted my simple code, I am not sure what you mean how am I sending the data. There is an option in the VS code for sending Direct messages to IoT hub. You can google that option, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-iot-toolkit/wiki/Send-D2C-Message-to-IoT-Hub